# ZyXEL P-2812HNU-F1, replacing the U-Boot on the board

Tags: firmware, linux, embedded, serial-communication

I want flash regular(non branded) firmware on ZyXEL P-2812HNU-F1 router, which have branded version of firmware (customized for local MSO provider).
To do this, I should first replace the U-Boot image on the board. The full procedure is described in [Wiki](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/zyxel/p2812hnu-fx#branded_and_nonbranded). However, this procedure is for installing **OpenWrt** on ZyXEL P-2812HNU-FX series. In my case I just want flash the regular unbranded firmware version from the manufacturer's repository, not OpenWrt.

What's not clear: do I need another special U-Boot version, tailored to regular generic (nonbranded) ZyXEL firmware, or I can use U-Boot version created for OpenWrt?

Comment: Did you have a look at the end of the wiki entry? This manual seems to be related: https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=221104

Comment: I'm not sure this is really about Reverse Engineering; looks like embedded development to me

Comment: Have read this too. I couldn't find the argument of ATSE command. ATSE x (where x is argument of ATSE command). I've tried various, but no one is worked.